# sql : Enable and Disable Triggers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have trigger on a table which is written longtime back and can’t retire or modify at this moment. There are lot of select statements are there which get fired irrespective of any condition in this trigger.

Now I have another Stored Procedure which will update the two columns in the above mentioned table and I don’t want any other operation or any queries which were written in the trigger needs to be fired when this operation ( calling SP) is performed.

So I though before I call the update statement in this stored procedure, I disable the update trigger on this table and once I done with update statement will again enable the trigger .

Is this is good idea ? Any issues with this approach? I will do this operation in transaction so that if anything goes wrong , it will come back to original stage .

Comment: humm, I think I saw this somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable/enable a trigger by hand.

It is a good idea, as long as you are sure that the trigger does not update some other field or table and if no other job launching that trigger may run at the same time.